# How do I leave horizontal mode?

Tags: text-mode

I was working on my resume and for some reason there is an error message that says "You can't use \moveleft in horizontal mode." I've been working on this for the past 45 minutes and I haven't really touched any of the formatting. I don't understand why I am getting this message.

Here is my code:

```
 \documentclass[centered,11pt,]{res} 

 \begin{document}


  % Establish mywidth as width of entire resume (since res.cls co-opts textwidth!):
 \newlength\mywidth
 \setlength\mywidth\textwidth
 \addtolength\mywidth{\sectionwidth}

 % Center the name over the entire width of resume:
 \moveleft0.5\hoffset\centerline{\Large \bf TIM H. JOO}

 % Contact info centered over entire width of resume:
 \raggedright \hspace*{-\sectionwidth}123 Sesame Street \hfill (123) 456-7890\\
 \raggedright \hspace*{-\sectionwidth}St. Paul, MN 12345 \hfill younrame@isp.com
 % Draw a horizontal line the whole width of resume:
 \vspace{-3 mm}
 \moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width \mywidth}
  \vspace{-8 mm}

 \begin{resume}
  blah blah blah
```

Using \leavehmode does not seem to work.

Comment: Always have a blank line before `\vspace`. You exit horizontal mode by issuing `\par` (a blank line does it).

Comment: `\vspace` isn't (unfortunately) `\vskip`. The `\vspace` is implemented via `\vadjust` primitive and this is a source of many many user confusions:). I don't understand why this implemetation was used. IMHO it is one of many examples of bad design of LaTeX.

Comment: You probably want to use \raisebox anyway.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would approach this:

```
\documentclass[centered,11pt,]{res} 
% Establish mywidth as width of entire resume (since res.cls co-opts textwidth!):

\newlength\mywidth
\setlength\mywidth\textwidth
\addtolength\mywidth{\sectionwidth}

\begin{document}

% Center the name over the entire width of resume:
\hspace*{-\hoffset}%%
\hspace*{\fill}%%
\makebox[0pt]{\textbf{\Large TIM H. JOO}}%%
\hspace*{\fill}%%

%  % Contact info centered over entire width of resume:
\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}123 Sesame Street  \hfill (123) 456-7890\newline
%% comment out the end of the line to avoid spurious whitespace from creeping in.
\hspace*{-\sectionwidth}St. Paul, MN 12345 \hfill younrame@isp.com%%
%% to adjust the vertical space without creating a new paragraph, call
%% \vspace before `\newline`.
\vspace{-3mm}%%
\newline
% Draw a horizontal line the whole width of resume:
\hspace*{-\hoffset}\rule{\resumewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{resume}


  blah blah blah

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

`\makebox` centers its content by default.  Setting its width to `0pt` allows for easy centering over the width of the paper (as I understood what you wanted).  The `\hspace*{\fill}` bracking this box centers the content on the space remaining on the line after the first `\hspace*{-\hoffset}`.

If you load the package `tabularx` you can more easily set up your address as you want:

```
\hspace{-\hoffset}%%
\begin{tabularx}{\resumewidth}{@{}Xr@{}}
  123 Sesame Street & (123) 456-7890 \\
  St.~Paul, MN 12345 & younrame@isp.com \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

The `@{}` before and after the column specifications removes the white space which `tabular` environments (and their kin) add between columns.  This way you get the material flush left and flush right as you seem to want.

Incidentally, using `\textbf{...}` is preferable to `\bf`.