# How to leave horizontal mode?

Tags: boxes

There is this question: [How do I leave horizontal mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201432/how-do-i-leave-horizontal-mode) - but there is no answer no how to leave horizontal mode.

I know there is a command `\leavevmode` ([Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode)); the post [What are vertical and horizontal modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13177/what-are-vertical-and-horizontal-modes) points to its definition:

> Plain, LaTeX and pdfTeX have built-in macros to make easier to switch from one mode to another such as \leavevmode, which is simply a void box that is opened:
>
> ```
> \protected\def\leavevmode{\unhbox \voidb@x}
> ```

Ok, but there is no `\leavehmode` command ?

So what command can I use to leave horizontal mode, and re-enter vertical mode - without artifacts as say new lines, or insertion of additional horizontal or vertical spaces?

Comment: It's simply `\par`. What you're asking in the final paragraph doesn't make sense: in horizontal mode you make paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks @egreg - but wouldn't `\par` insert a new line/line break as well?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding what vertical and horizontal modes are.

First of all, let me consider the relationship between vertical and horizontal mode. TeX always starts off in vertical mode.

Under certain circumstances (precisely when it sees a *horizontal command*), TeX leaves vertical mode and starts horizontal mode in order to make paragraphs. You can't “leave” this mode in other ways than ending the paragraph.

You're probably misled by the name of the `\leavevmode` command, which could have been named something like `\StartMakingAParagraphIfItMakesSense`; the command does `\unhbox\v@idbox` and `\unhbox` is a horizontal command, so

- (unrestricted) horizontal mode is started if TeX was in vertical mode,
- nothing happens if TeX is in horizontal mode or in math mode.

The only way to end unrestricted horizontal mode is by issuing (explicitly or implicitly) a primitive `\par` command. Every *vertical command*, if found when TeX is in unrestricted horizontal mode, issues a `\par` token.

Note that `\par` might not mean the primitive `\par`, but the redefined `\par` should at some point execute the primitive `\par` or strange things will happen: the simple

```
\def\par{}
x\vskip1pt
```

will start an infinite loop, for example, because `\vskip` will continue to issue `\par` in order to be executed in the vertical mode that's never reached.

You can start vertical mode when in horizontal mode by opening a `\vbox` or `\vtop`, but the resulting list will eventually be appended to the horizontal list being built, so this doesn't seem what you're looking for.

There is an escape to the surrounding vertical mode: if TeX finds `\vadjust{...}` in (unrestricted) horizontal mode, it will package the vertical list given as argument, and this list will be inserted between the line where the command happens to be and the next one, after the paragraph has been formed. Such a vertical list will be appended *before* the interline glue. So

```
abc\vadjust{\vskip3pt} text text ... text
```

will have 3pt of additional vertical space between the first and second lines of the paragraph.

There is no symmetry between vertical mode and horizontal mode, because they do very different things.

Comment: Many thanks @egreg - you nailed it, both with "_You can't “leave” this mode in other ways than ending the paragraph_" and with "_You're probably misled by the name of the \leavevmode command ..._"; that was indeed the core of my confusion. Moved the accept here; thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to end the current horizontal list and enter vertical mode the command is the (primitive) `\par`.

If you want to start a nested vertical list that will be added to the current horizontal list when completed the command is `\vbox{...}`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle - but doesn't `\par` insert a new line/line break too?

Comment: "inserting a new line" is a general english language description for a specific technical Tex behaviour which (as far as I can guess) is "end horizontal mode".

Comment: Ok, thanks for that - so, I can consider them being synonyms I guess... I guess, I was hoping for a way to cheat `\ifhmode` without issuing `\par` which would insert a break; but apparently there isn't one... Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: @sdaau I can't even _guess_ what you would want the behaviour of that to be. Where would you want the vertical material to go if you did not put it _after_ (ie below) the horizontal material you had just left?

Comment: Well, the thing is - I want to insert a tikzpicture which shouldn't take up any space (remember picture, overlay) inside a `\titleformat*`, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235818/using-titleformat-with-tikzpicture-horizontal-mode, but the tikzpicture does a `\leavevmode` anyways, which subsequently breaks my approach. I myself cannot imagine what's going on in this context either - I just know somewhat correct rendering is shown if I keep going after all the "Entered in horizontal mode" errors - so I'd like to get rid of these errors `:)`

Comment: In other words, if there was a TeX "cursor" that changes its x/y position as boxes are added, I'd like a command that doesn't change the cursor position, only the horizontal mode as detected by `\ifhmode`...

Comment: @sdaau That is `\vbox` then. But also (depending what you mean) it could be `\par` `\par` just ends the current horizontal mode, that causes the paragraph to be broken into lines and added to the current vertical list, it doesn't cause any additional vertical space to be added (`\parskip` glue will be added by a _following_ _horizontal_ command that triggers a new horizontal list)